# C# Splitting JSONObject from database into two objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

I am developing a restful api using ASP.NET MVC.I need to return a JSON response structured like this:

```
 {
    "config": {
        "type": "custom",
        "name": "Deals and Offers",
        "template": "customTextImageActionCard1"

    },
    "cardContent": [{

            "display": {
                "primaryMessage": "",
                "primaryButton": "FIND FLIGHTS",
                "dismissButton": "Dismiss"
            },
            "action": {
                "pageId": "webview",
                "customLink": "<Any required url>",
                "params": []
            }
        },
        {
            "display": { 

                "priority": "2",
                "cardId": "18032003",
                "title": "Ultimate Flexibility",
                
            },
            "action": {
                "customLink": "",
                "pageId": "browser",
                "params": []
            }
        },...
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(string appCountry = null, string appLanguage = null)
        {  
            DealsEntities context = new DealsEntities();            
            var data = new
            {
                type = "custom",
                name = "Deals and Offers",
                template = "customTextImageActionCard1"
            };
            return Ok(new { config = data, cardContent = context.cards.ToList() });      
        }
```

I have achieved this response:

```
{
    "config": {
        "type": "custom",
        "name": "Deals and Offers",
        "template": ""
    },
    "cardContent": [
        {
            "primaryMessage": "",
            "primaryButton": "",
            "dismissButton": "Dismiss",
            "pageId": "browser",
            "customLink": "",
            "params": null
        },
        {
            "primaryMessage": "\"Kota Kinabalu from MYR 179",
            "primaryButton": "Book Now",
            "dismissButton": "Dismiss",
            "pageId": "webview",
            "customLink": "",
            "params": null
        },...
```

The cards  data is stored as rows in the database.How can I split the card objects into the display object and action object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the responses. I managed to get it working with the following code.
I modified my model to have action and display attributes

```
public partial class card
    {
        public string primaryMessage { get; set; }
        public string primaryButton { get; set; }
        public string dismissButton { get; set; }
        public string pageId { get; set; }
        public string customLink { get; set; }
        public string @params { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
        public string display { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I added the code below to the controller method.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(string appCountry = null, string appLanguage = null)
        {
            DealsEntities context = new DealsEntities();
            IEnumerable<card> cards = context.cards;
            var data2 = cards.Select(x => new 
            {
                display = new
                {
                    cardId = x.cardId,
                    priority = x.priority,
                    title = x.title,
                    banner = x.banner,
                    primaryMessage = x.primaryMessage,
                    primaryButton = x.primaryButton,
                    dismissButton = x.dismissButton
                },
                action = new
                {
                    page_id = x.pageId,
                    custom_link = x.customLink,
                    @params = x.@params
                }
            });          

            var data = new
            {
                type = "custom",
                name = "Deals and Offers",
                template = "customTextImageActionCard1"

            };
            return Ok(new { config = data, cardContent = data2});
        }
```

And voila. Hope it helps someone in future.

Comment: Problem here is that you are not really having any place to control the object constraints. Using anonymous types is not following the Postels Law. Id still recommend building the objects and give them business knowledge as what that api should return. Your solution works - but its not great I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a structure.

```
public struct ApiData
{
    public Config config;
    public List<CardContent> cardContent;
}

public struct Config
{
    public string type;
    public string name;
    public string template;
}

public struct CardContent
{
    public Display display;
    public Action action;
}

public struct Display
{
    public string primaryMessage;
    public string primaryButton;
    public string dismissButton;
}

public struct Action
{
    public string pageId;
    public string customLink; 
    public List<Params> @params; // You probably want to rename params since the compiler takes it as a keyword.
}

public struct Params
{
    // Add whatever you want.
}
```

Then in your code create a `new ApiData()` and assign the values.

Example:

```
public static ApiData assign()
{
    var data = new ApiData();

    var config = new Config();
    config.name = "";
    config.template = "";
    config.type = "";

    var cardContent = new CardContent();
    var action = new Action();
    action.customLink = "";

    cardContent.action = action;

    data.config = config;

    if (data.cardContent is null) data.cardContent = new List<CardContent>() { cardContent };
    else
    {
        data.cardContent.Add(cardContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend creating a .NET type containing all you need.

Then construct that type with proper objects, and return it from your API method.